# Why does this command not work on Windows via SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh

I'd like to send websites to be opened on my Windows PC from my MacBook via some automations involving SSH.

The following command works fine when I'm running it on my PC, but it only shows up in the task manager when I run it via SSH.

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -private-window reddit.com

Tried to use it with the runas command as well.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH session works like a normal user session, except it's not given access to the UI (meanings, SSH has no start button to click on, no firefox window and so)

While firefox DOES PROVIDE a way to run the browser for headless (no UI) sessions, you're still expecting your SSH user-session to do something as your non-ssh user session. This is why you see the process running, but you don't see the window.

Please have a look at different thread on the SE:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display
Which explains how to achieve what you want in a different way